# Multiple databases or tables with prefix?

Tags: database-design, multi-tenant

I was creating an Accounting ERP for a multibrach company.Normally i would keep different databases for different branches, Can anyone tell me which is the standard way?
1) create databases respective to branches
2) keep single database and arrange tables with branch prefix

Comment: There are many questions and answers on multi-tenant designs. Check those.

Answer (score 1):

It's not simply a question of plugging values into an equation and, hey presto, you have an answer (as @dbdemon also points out - no standard solution).

You need to put considerable thought into this - it could be a choice which affects you for a considerable time.

A few things you **should** do **before** you start coding:

- Gather detailled requirements (as kindly suggested by @Peter)
- Check out the threads and a few of my answers on multi-tenancy [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007%20tenancy). Also, as suggested by @Colin'tHart, do a search on this site for other posts related to multi-tenancy.
- You could also download a few Open Source apps - use your search engine of choice - duckduckgo got me a few [links](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=open%20source%20erp&t=hy&ia=web).
- Take a look at [databaseanswers](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm) and their schemas - something there might be of interest/help.
- Do a bit of prototyping - see what "fits" with your company/clients/stakeholders requirements and/or your company's skillset in the coding/database areas.

Comment: TLDR;) Start with gathering some detailed requirements..

Comment: @Peter Rearranged as per your kind suggestion! :-)

Comment: haa! Sorry. Not a dig at you. But a poke at Op. I seem to be seeing lots of posts lately asking for opinions on best approach yet they lack context, groundwork research and mostly evidently... requirements.

Comment: @Peter - not a problem. I just gave a few pointers and you were, in fact, correct to give me a  pointer of your own by err... pointing me to the 0th law of computing - find out what you **actually** need before doing anything else!

Comment: I would also mention using Schemas for separation instead of a prefix of the table name (unless that is what the O.P. meant by "prefix", but I would state it clearly to be sure). And, not sure what I think of the data models available at "databaseanswers". I mean, for an experienced data modeler they might be fodder for inspiring an idea, but they could just as easily be very misleading to the inexperienced given that data models are very specific to the requirements of a specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a standard solution, but in the choice between a multiple databases and prefixed tables, I would think multiple databases would make the most sense for the following reasons:

- Easier to grant permissions so each user gets access to their own data only, which in turn is helpful to mitigate security breaches
- Easier to create separate backups for each branch
- A smaller number of tables in a database makes it easier to understand. Also consider scale: Remember that the number of branches could grow significantly. (Or you would hope for that, I'm sure!)
- The meaning of prefixes are not always intuitive
- Stored procedures, triggers and events meant to affect only one branch can be kept in each branch database, and all such procedures, triggers and events would be identical for every branch, which means less maintenance and simpler logic in the procedure code